# GraphQL: How to restrict fields server-side across queries?

Tags: graphql

Let's say I have a User type that contains the following fields:

```
type User {
  name: String
  username: String
  someOtherField1: String
  someOtherField2: String
  someOtherField3: String
  someOtherField4: String
  creditCardNumber: String
}
```

If I am querying for myself, it's okay to return all fields, because the information is mine. So returning `creditCardNumber` to the client is no biggie. But if I am querying for someone else, I should only be able to access the public info on the returned user. Returning `creditCardNumber` would be terrible. And even if I don't code the query on the client to do so, what would prevent a malicious user from digging into the code, updating the client-side query to include `creditCardNumber`, and executing it?

What is the best way to achieve this level of field restriction across queries in GraphQL? My only thought on this so far is to create a separate `UserSearch` type, i.e.

```
type UserSearch {
  name: String
  username: String
  someOtherField1: String
  someOtherField2: String
  someOtherField3: String
  someOtherField4: String
}
```

which excludes the private fields, however this does not feel DRY as you'd be creating many types that are 90% similar in structure form each other.

Is there a cleaner way to implement this, that doesn't create unnecessary types or duplicate fields?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, GraphQL types are maybe types, which means you can return null to any field.

Which means, inside the `resolve` function of your `creditCardNumber` field, you could check if the current user is the user being fetched, and if so, you return the number. Otherwise, you return null.

To access "contexted" data such as the current user, GraphQL let you pass an object `context` when executing the graphql function:

```
graphql(schema, query, rootValue, context) // <-- the last parameter
```

And you will find this object in each field `resolve` function signature:

```
...
resolve: (object, args, context) => {
  // Third argument is your object
},
....
```

So what you can do, is pass the current logged user in the context:

```
graphql(schema, query, rootValue, { user: getCurrentLoggedUser() })
```

And in your `User` type, inside the `creditCardNumber` field resolve function:

```
creditCardNumber: {
  ...
  resolve: (user, args, context) => {
    if (user.id === context.user.id)
      return user.creditCardNumber;

    return null;
  },
  ...
}
```

If you are using `graphql-express`, the context is by default the request, [and you can customize it](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#options).

Comment: I can't believe this has to be handled in resolve of every field that needs to be filtered.

Comment: you can use directives to limit access to limit access to specific field https://github.com/LawJolla/prisma-auth0-example/issues/12