# How do authorization with GraphQL and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authorization, graphql

I am considering the possibility of applying GraphQL in my project, which is based on Laravel 5.4. Now I use REST API, and I have no problems with authorization ([I use Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/)): I return the data set to the user in accordance with its role and rights and this corresponds to the business logic of the application.

Now I want to use GraphQL, but I do not understand the mechanism for embedding business logic and authorization so that I can return a set of data, depending on the rights of the user requesting the data.

Tell me, please, how can this be done? Are there any better practices for integrating GraphQL into Laravel framework?

Comment: I've just answered a similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641553/graphql-how-to-restrict-fields-server-side-across-queries/44649042#44649042. Let me know if that answers your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use [this](https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql) package you can do that easily.

For example, define multiple schemes like this:
https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql#schemas

Then in your routes/web.php file define

```
Route::get('/graphql/secret', ['middleware' => ['api:auth']], function () {
```

});

Public data can be accessed on routes like this:
http://your.domain/graphql?query=query+FetchUsers{users{name}}

Protected data can be accessed on routes like this:
http://your.domain/graphql/secret?query=query+FetchUsers{users{id,email,name}}